# python discord.py background task stop main func

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

Using: discord.py
I trying to run background task. But after it starts main func like on_message stops working.

Code

```
async def on_ready():
        print('x')
        x = "true"
        client.loop.create_task(my_background_task(x))
async def my_background_task(x):
        while True:
                #do stuff
                await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord 
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   #your on_ready code here

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   #your on_message code here

async def my_background_task(x):
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed():
        #do stuff
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task(True))
client.run('token')
```